# How to use Windows Indexing Service on Win7 for source code searching?

Tags: c++

I have create a indexing catalog for my source code on Win7 but I can't find a tool to perform the searching.. Any pointer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the Win7 indexing uses the old Indexing service then perhaps it's similar to how it is in XP.

There you can access the search functionality via Computer Management, `%SystemRoot%\system32\compmgmt.msc /s`.

Drill down to Services and Applications -> Indexing Services -> Query the Catalog.

I once made a C# GUI for that. Still have it, called "Find Files Fast". Immediately after, while it was still only in rough infancy, both Google and Microsoft made available indexing-based fast local search tools.

So, another way might be to just download such tool from Microsoft or Google (Google's used Google's own indexing, as I recall, and had/has some privacy issues).

One problem with Microsoft's indexing service is that by default it's configured, at least on XP, to not support queries for ".h" files... Utterly silly, I can't think of any reason why. But it makes it less than ideal to use to search for source code.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Hi Alf, Thank you for your reply.

1. Applications -> Indexing Services -> Query the Catalog.
   Lees:I can't find it in Win7 but it is there in XP somehow.

2. So, another way might be to just download such tool from Microsoft or Google
   Lees: Would you please point me out where I can find the query tool you mentioned here?

Comment: @user494413: I googled it. Microsoft's [Windows Search](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx) docs don't appear to say whether it uses Index Server. Google's search seems to be available only bundled with [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/). Perhaps I should start looking again at my old Find Files Fast utility... Cheers,